# Deflation in eigenvalue and eigenvector computation

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, numerical-methods, eigenvalue

Using this method, I should be able to get eigenvalues by getting the greatest value in each iteration.
But, what my code enables to get is only the first eingenvalue (and not necessarily the greatest) and I don't know where is the problem.

```
function [Vect,Vp]=PID(A,precision)
    nbVal= 50;
    [n,m]=size(A);
    X=zeros(n,1);
    X(1,1)=1;
    Vect=zeros(n,min(n,nbVal));
    Vp=zeros(1,min(n,nbVal));
    XG=zeros(1,n);
    j=1;
    
for i=1:min(nbVal,n)
    Y = rand(n,1);
    while (max(abs(Y/norm(Y)-X/norm(X))>=precision))
        
        X=Y/norm(Y);
        Y=A*X;
    end
    Vect(:,i)=X;
    % To prevent a division by 0
    while (X(j,1)==0 && j<=n) 
        j = j + 1;
    end    
    if X(j,1)~=0
    Vp(1,i) =Y(j,1)/X(j,1); 
    end
    
    % Wielandt Deflation
     YG= rand(1,n);
    while (max(abs(YG/norm(YG)-XG/norm(XG)))>=precision )
        XG=YG/norm(YG);
        YG=XG*A;
    end    

    A2=A-Vp(1,i)*(X*XG)/(XG*X);
    A=A2;

    end

end
```

Comment: You need to provide debugging details.

Comment: What do you call "the first" ?